# How to store the values into a dictionary using jquery

Tags: java, jquery

I have a function that will return all the properties and the values of an element under the mouse pointer. But I'm not able to add those values into a dictionary which I want to use it for some other purpose. 
Can someone help me out in this. Any help is greatly appreciated. The code goes as follows:

```
Public void function1(){
IJavaScriptExecutor j;
j.ExecuteAsyncScript(@"return $('body').hover(function(evt){Var X=document.elementFromPoint(evt.pageX,evt pageY);Var att={}; $(X.attributes).each(function(){att[this.nodeName]=this.nodeValue;});console.log(att);});");
//want to use the dictionary containing their properties and values
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like jquery?

Comment: Javascript which is executed via Java :D

Comment: I've never seen this syntax: `document.element froM point(evt.pageX,evt pageY)`...